# Qt5 installation and path configuration

Tags: 13.10, qt, qt5

I have installed Qt5 from the Qt5 project site, to the following directory

```
/opt/Qt5
```

I would also like to mention that I had Qt4 installed previously, I have removed all instances of Qt4 through the software center.

Now that I issue `designer` from the command prompt, the system gives the following error:

```
designer: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer': No such file or directory
```

What can be done to correct this problem?

Comment: Qt5 is packaged and available in the archives for Ubuntu 13.10. Why didn't you install it from there?

Comment: And if you need the latest Qt 5.2.1, it's now available in the 14.04 development version

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Replace Default Qt version paths in:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/default.conf`
or in newer releases `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf`:

```
/opt/Qt5/bin
/opt/Qt5/lib
```

Check:

```
qtchooser -print-env
```

Reference: [`man qtchooser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/qtchooser.1.html)

Comment: Actually the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/default.conf` is a symlink to the one in `/usr/share/qtchooser/default.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Proper path to qt default config: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf`

Comment: You may want to suggest this as an edit to the other answer. The answer section should be reserved for entire answers.

Comment: Yes qtchooser will look at the default.conf, you can create a symlink `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/default.conf`

Answer (score 2):

For all of those who didn't uninstal old version and are wondering how to change the qt directory location.
The correct way is to export the QT_SELECT variable and add the custom ~/.config/qtchooser/somename.conf file.

This will be a qt installation visible in qtchooser -l under "somename".
So that:

```
 QT_SELECT=somename; qtchooser -print-env
```

Will return your custom location.
The downside of changing the default.conf is that it might invalidate where your old qt version is found, when I did change it to /some/path, after executing:

```
QT_SELECT=qt4; qtchooser -print-env
```

It find the newer version on my path, however with the ~/config/qtchooser/somename.conf the earlier version is intact.

It is mentioned at the end of the `man qtchooser` help:

> FILES
>          /etc/xdg/qtchooser/*.conf
>                 System-wide configuration files. Each has two lines, the first is the path to the binaries and the second is the path to the Qt
>   libraries. If a default.conf is provided,  the  settings
>                 from it will be automatically used in case nothing else is selected.
>
> $HOME/.config/qtchooser/*.conf
>    configuration files

Answer (score 1):

**Directory location for ubuntu pip install qt5-tools:**
`/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/bin/designer`

Maybe add it to path or .bashrc.

`export PATH=$PATH:/home/"userName"/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/bin`

and 'or' you can put a link in your home directory to run "./designer"

`ln -s /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qt5_applications/Qt/bin/designer /home/user/designer`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers suggesting to check the configuration in the qtchooser, but I didn't manage to get it to work. The solution that worked for me was simply to add the right qt version to PATH. 5.11 in my case.

```
export PATH="/opt/qt511/bin:$PATH"
```