# OBS application crashes on trackpad tap events

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, qt5, video-streaming

OBS crashes (segfault) when I tap the trackpad while the mouse is over the OBS window. Using the mouse does not cause this crash.

The guy on this [forum post](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/issues-with-mouse-and-crashing.2699/) ran into issues with OBS, specifically mouse and crashing issues.

My installation ran into the same problem running on an XPS 13, x64 Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

```
[1]    17198 segmentation fault (core dumped)  obs
```

Here is the output of `gdb ods`... seems to be a qt5 problem.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffda837cbb in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
```

Additional info

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

OBS studio was installed using `apt-get install obs-studio`.

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy obs-studio libqt5gui5
obs-studio:
  Installed: 0.16.2.1-544~trusty
  Candidate: 0.16.2.1-544~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 0.16.2.1-544~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libqt5gui5:
  Installed: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3
  Candidate: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3
  Version table:
 *** 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add how you installed it, plus the output of `apt-cache policy obs-studio libqt5gui5`

Comment: okay, edited post to include this information

Answer (score 1):

That was same version used to build the obs, here is  [the related build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/291223353/buildlog_ubuntu-trusty-amd64.obs-studio_0.16.2.1-544%7Etrusty_BUILDING.txt.gz). You better go with bug report against obs.

But before reporting, test the last unstable build from [OBS Studio Unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eobsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio-unstable)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

> The Linux version of OBS is still under development and contains many
> bugs, but if you're feeling brave, and can install Ubuntu PPAs, then
> you can give this a try.
>
> <sup>Source: [OBS Project, Ubuntu PPA Installation Instructions](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/ubuntu-ppa-installation-instructions.16495/)</sup>

Comment: Tried the workaround, same problem. Maybe there is a workaround for the qt5 component because that seems to be causing the crash?

Comment: @Jamie, you may try the last Qt 5.7.1 from https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2 .  See  here how to set as default  https://askubuntu.com/questions/435564/qt5-installation-and-path-configuration . Qt team says that they try to keep backward compatibility, however if it fails, we may try to rebuild/recompile  obs vs Qt 5.7.1 (up to you to take this adventure :-) )

Comment: @Jamie, any results with last Qt?

Comment: The problem seems solved, but I'm not sure how. I installed QT 5.7.1 to a local folder but did not make it the default. When I ran `qtchooser -print-env`, I noticed that the default version of QT was 4.x. Then I ran `obs -qt=5`, which worked (no crashes), and after that, running `obs` normally without the flag runs without crashing. All in all I'm not sure what fixed the issue.

Comment: @Jamie, that seems  the cause (default qt) because obs was built with qt5 only. If you can confirm, `obs -qt=4` does crash.  Then you may write it as answer.

Comment: If only! I believe the `-qt` flag was a red herring, the flag has no effect. `obs -qt=4`also does not crash, and neither does any bad value for the flag. In addition moving the local installation of Qt has no effect. I am not sure how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jamie, Are you using obs from obs-studio-unstable ppa? if so you try downgrade to obs-studio ppa version `sudo apt-get install obs-studio=0.16.2.1-544~trusty` , reboot then try if crash as before.